# Stored proc temporary table with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

Hello in a stored procedure, i create a temp-table filled with a select wich execute a function to return date recurrences.

The creation of my temp table looks like this :

```
    BEGIN
        insert into #tmp_recu
        SELECT * FROM dbo.CrontabSchedule('0 0 * * *', '2017-2-1', '2017-2-28')
    END
```

After creating this temp-table, i execute a query using this temp table like this :

```
Select * from mission
Cross Join #temp_recu
```

The problem is i'd like to remplace the '0 0 * * *' in my temp-table creation by a field from mission table (field named recurrence), so how could i do that?

Thanks !

EDIT

Actually, in my query, i'd like to call the function 'CrontabSchedule'  and put in parameter a field from 'mission' table like this :

```
select * from mission m
cross join select * from dbo.CronTabSchedule(mission.reccurence,'2017-1-1','2017-1-31')
```

It works when i called the function like this

```
select * from dbo.CronTabSchedule('0 0 * * *','2017-1-1','2017-1-31')
```

But when i replace '0 0 * * *' by 'Mission.recurrence' (which contains the recurrence pattern of each mission), i have an error :

> The multi-part identifier "Mission.recurrence" could not be bound.

CrontabSchedule code :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CrontabSchedule](@Expression [nvarchar](100), @Start[datetime], @End [datetime])
RETURNS  TABLE (
[Occurrence] [datetime] NULL
) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [NCrontabSQL].[NContab.SQL.SqlCrontab].[GetOccurrences]
```

The function return a table with one column named 'Occurence' and contains à list of dates.

Comment: Just don't `select *` and select only the fields you want? Or have I missed something?

Comment: Are you looking for a table valued function?

Comment: see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It depends on the way `dbo.CrontabSchedule` work and how you define `#tmp_recu`. Can you show us both of them?
A possible solution is to edit `dbo.CrontabSchedule` to return your value in the first place, Can we change function definition or do you want a seperate query?

Comment: I have edited for more informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty vague question here but I am assuming that CronTabSchedule must be a table valued function (hopefully an inline version but that is another topic). If I am correct you could use CROSS APPLY for this quite easily.

```
select * 
from mission m
cross apply dbo.CronTabSchedule(m.reccurence,'2017-1-1','2017-1-31') cts
```